# Writing a recursive function within function in python: deprecated?

Tags: python, recursion, closures, pep8

Recently, I've gotten into the habit of writing recursive functions within wrapper functions in python. For example, my old habit of calling recursive functions from a wrapper is as follows:

```
def sortedArrayToBST(nums):   
    return _toBST(nums)

def _toBST(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0: return None
    mid = len(nums) / 2
    root = TreeNode(nums[mid])
    root.left = _toBST(nums[:mid])         
    root.right = _toBST(nums[mid+1:])
    return root
```

On the other hand, my new habit is to embed this recursive function inside the wrapper:

```
def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums):

    def toBST(nums_):
        if len(nums_) == 0: return None
        mid = len(nums_) / 2
        root = TreeNode(nums_[mid])
        root.left = toBST(nums_[:mid])
        root.right = toBST(nums_[mid+1:])
        return root

    return toBST(nums)
```

([Problem source here](https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/))

The reason I do it is because you probably don't want to pollute the namespace with helper functions. Plus you could treat the helper function as a closure, in case you would like to access variables from the wrapper function.

But is this style of code writing deprecated? I can't find anywhere within PEP 8 that states that embedding functions within functions is discouraged.

Comment: In the nested version, the helper function will be re-defined each time the outer function is called.

Comment: @augurar: That's true. But unless I was writing a very large recursive function, this shouldn't be a problem to redefine the nested function every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no stricture against nested functions in Python.  I don't think that leading the name with an underscore is warranted.  Because is a nested function definition it won't conflict with names outside of that local scope so just use the most naturally flowing name (as if you were reading the function to someone and explaining how it works).

On the other hand recursion is best avoided in Python due to the lack of tail recursion elimination.  I'd suggest reading this: http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html ...and see if you can transform your code into an iterative implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Jim. You're right, recursion in python is quite slow. The reason why I was practicing recursive code is for the sake of interview questions (it's faster to write recursive code than iterative code). When I'm writing source code though, I avoid recursion.

Comment: I changed my code to get rid of the leading underscores in front of `toBST`. Thanks for the suggestion.